# Why is my interaction energy not converging to zero?

Tags: vasp

I have been calculating the interaction energy of a single CO2 molecule with a cristobalite silica surface (~300 atoms) using single point calculations in VASP. As I calculated the energies and plotted them I saw that the energy is not converging to zero at longer distances. I am attaching the INCAR file and how the energy plot looks like. Can someone kindle suggest me a solution. I am using a 1*1*1 gamma grid of KPOINTS. [image]

```
    # ----- SCF of adsorption calculation ------
# ==========================================

# General Setup
  SYSTEM   = SCF of silica/CO2 
  NWRITE   = 2
  PREC = NORMAL    
  ENCUT = 450
  ISTART =  0      #Default: ISTART = 1 if WAVECAR exists, = 0 else
  ICHARG =  2      #Default: ICHARG = 2 if ISTART=0, = 0 else

# Electronic Relaxation
  NELM = 150 #Increase the iterations.
  EDIFF    = 1.0E-05  # Increase the stopping criteria for ESC
  LREAL    = AUTO   # Real space projection
  IALGO    = 38       # Electronic algorithm minimization
  ADDGRID  = .TRUE.   # Improve the grid accuracy


# Ionic Relaxation
# EDIFFG   = 1.0E-04  # Stopping criteria for ionic self cons steps
  NSW      = 0        # Max Number of ISC steps: 0- Single Point
  ISIF     = 2        # Ionic Relaxation
  IBRION   = -1       # Single Point
  SIGMA    = 0.10     # Insulators/semiconductors=0.1  metals=0.05
  ISMEAR   = 0        # Partial Occupancies for each Orbital
                      # -5 DOS, -2 from file, -1 Fermi Smear, 0 Gaussian Smear

  LCHARG = .FALSE. #do not write CHGCAR file
  LWAVE  = .FALSE. #write to WAVECAR file

# vdW corrections
  IVDW   =  11
    VDW_RADIUS = 10.0

# Exchange correlation treatment:
   GGA    = PE

# Parallelization
  NCORE=4
```

Answer (score 2):

The energy is not expected to converge to zero (for very large distances). For example, if you were to calculate the energy for a CO (carbon monoxide) molecule as a function of internuclear distance between the C and O nuclei, the energy as the internuclear distance becomes infinitely large, will converge to the sum of the individual C atom energy and O atom energy:

$$\tag{1}
\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} E_{~\textrm{CO}}~~(r) = E_{~\textrm{C}} + E_{~\textrm{O}}~.
$$

In your case, the energy is expected to converge to the sum of the CO2 energy and the energy of the ~300-atom surface. If you calculate the CO2 energy and the energy of the ~300-atom surface individually, and add them together, I would anticipate that you would get the energy of about -0.02 eV that we see in your figure.

The energy ***difference*** can be expected to converge to zero, but not the total energies.

Comment: My appologies if my question was not well stated. By interaction energy, I mean the Energy_(slab+CO2)-E_(slab)-E_(CO2) which is actually the difference. The "distance" in the plot corresponds to the CO2 molecule moving away from the surface of the silica. This is why I was concerned with the convergence

Comment: If that formula was in your question or the vertical axis of your plot, then it would have been more clear. The input file doesn't make it clear that you're using that equation, either. Also, the title of your question asks why the "interaction energy" doesn't converge to 0, which may have contributed to me not noticing that the vertical axis label said "interaction energy **difference**". Do you also have the individual energies for "Slab + CO2", "Slab alone" and "CO2 alone"? What happens when you do the calculation with a distance of 1000 Angstroms, or 100 Angstroms?

Comment: How about the VDW_RADIUS = 10.0? why did you specifiy that? Could you try to omit that option and see if there is any difference at high distances

Comment: @NikeDattani I do have those individual energies calculated as well. For all those single point calculations I used the same input file hence I included the single input file. Using those values i calculate the difference of energy which corresponds to the interaction energy. I haven't calculated with such a large distance. The largest separation I have considered is 10 Angstroms. So far it has been consistent with energy (difference) value converging at larger distances but not towards zero.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez I tried that value arbitrarily. I could not find the default value for that in the VASP manual. I tried to omit that value and all i got for the energy profile was a vertical line around 3 Angstroms.